# SQL Server Reporting Services Authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am running a .NET MVC 3 web application. I am embedding reports into my webpage through a webform. Below is my class for the webform that is passing authentication credentials to the report server and also displaying the report in the reportviewer webform but I am still getting a access is denied error. Any suggestions?

```
public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new MyReportServerCredentials();

        //Sets the report server based upon environment
        string reportServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url-reportServer"].ToString();

        //Sets the report path based upon the environment and the report name based upon which report is selected (variable passed through URL)
        string reportPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["url-reportPath"].ToString() + Request.QueryString["reportName"];

        // Set the processing mode for the ReportViewer to Remote to read from server
        reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;

        ServerReport serverReport = reportViewer.ServerReport;

        // Set the report server URL and report path
        serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(reportServer);
        serverReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public sealed class MyReportServerCredentials : IReportServerCredentials
    {
        public WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                // Use the default Windows user.  Credentials will be
                // provided by the NetworkCredentials property.
                return null;
            }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                // Read the user information from the Web.config file.  
                // By reading the information on demand instead of 
                // storing it, the credentials will not be stored in 
                // session, reducing the vulnerable surface area to the
                // Web.config file, which can be secured with an ACL.

                // User name
                string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyReportViewerUser"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                    throw new Exception("Missing user name from web.config file");

                // Password
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyReportViewerPassword"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                    throw new Exception("Missing password from web.config file");

                // Domain
                string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyReportViewerDomain"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                    throw new Exception("Missing domain from web.config file");

                return new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string userName, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            userName = null;
            password = null;
            authority = null;

            // Not using form credentials
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Check to see that Report Server config file has RSWindowsNegotiate in authentication before NTLM setting.
2. Enable identity impersonation.
3. Set server principal names and kerberos authentication if both the servers are not able to communicate